# Betti number of graded ideal and graded quotients

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, graded-modules, monomial-ideals

For a monomial ideal $I$ of a polynomial ring $S$ with degree $b$, Theorem 1.34 of the ``Combinatorial Commutative Algebra" says that

$$\beta_{i,b}(I) = \beta_{i+1,b}(S/I)$$

with a proof stating that

> use a minimal free resolution of $I$ achieved by snipping off the copy of $S$ occurring in homological degree 0 of a minimal free resolution of $S/I$.

This is immediate if the homological degree 0 part of the free resolution, say $F_{0}$, is $S$; however, how this proof is applied when $F_{0}=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n}S$ with $n>1$? It seems that $\text{im}(F_{1}) \subset F_{0}$ may be a submodule of $F_{0}$ which is not equivalent to $I$. Could you give me any hint to understand this proof?

Comment: But you can choose which resolution you're using, so choose to use one with $F_0=S$. (And indeed, saying *minimal* free resolution means you are using such a resolution.)

Comment: @EricWofsey How can you assure that we have a minimal resolution with $F_0=S$?

Comment: Just start with the quotient map $S\to S/I$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Is there a theorem ensuring that such a construction starting with $S \to S/I$ gives minimal free resolution?

Comment: Well, how do you know that *any* minimal free resolution exists?  The usual proof constructs it step by step and in this case the first step would be using $S\to S/I$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh... I see... Thank you very much! I will review the existence of minimal free resolution again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps another$^1$ proof helps to illuminate things: consider the short exact sequence

$$0 \longrightarrow I\longrightarrow S \longrightarrow S/I\longrightarrow 0$$

and take the long exact sequence for $\mathrm{Tor}^S(-,k)$. Since $S$ is projective its Tor-groups vanish, and the connecting morphism induces *natural* isomorphisms

$$\delta : \mathrm{Tor}^S_{j+1}(S/I,k) \longrightarrow \mathrm{Tor}^S_j(I,k).$$

Taking dimension gives your equality, if you recall that the Tor-dimension gives you the dimension of generators of a minimal resolution.

1: One can think of this as another incarnation of "snipping off the copy of $S$", as the SES above is precisely the truncation of the beginning of the minimal resolution of $S/I$.